# Check domain using selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to check for some domains using selenium in VBA
Here's my try

```
Option Explicit
Sub Check_Domain()
    Dim bot As New WebDriver
    Dim sDomain As String

    sDomain = "facebookopop.com"
    bot.Start "chrome", "https://ae.godaddy.com/domainsearch/find?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck=" & sDomain
    bot.Get "/"

    Dim eleTaken As Object, eleAvailable As Object

    bot.Wait 3000

    On Error Resume Next
    Set eleTaken = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[contains(.,'Domain Taken')]/ancestor::span[1]")
    Set eleAvailable = bot.FindElementByXPath("//text()[contains(.,'Domain Available')]/ancestor::span[1]")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not eleTaken Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Not Avaialable"
    ElseIf Not eleAvailable Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "Avaialable"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Unknown"
    End If
    Stop
End Sub
```

The code runs slowly and at the same time it doesn't give me correct results all the time .. How can I check for the existence of an element in an easy way and avoid errors?

I don't know why the following code doesn't work

```
Sub Check_Domain_Advanced()
Dim bot As New WebDriver
Dim sDomain As String
Dim c As Range
Dim ele As Object
Dim t
Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10

bot.Start "chrome"

For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If Not IsEmpty(c.Value) Then
        sDomain = c.Value
        bot.ExecuteScript "window.open(arguments[0])", "https://ae.godaddy.com/domainsearch/find?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck=" & sDomain
        bot.SwitchToNextWindow

        t = Timer
        Do
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While bot.FindElementsByCss("span[class='domain-name-text h2']").Count = 0

        Set ele = bot.FindElementByCss("span[class='domain-name-text h2']")

        If ele.IsPresent Then
            If InStr(ele.Text, "available") Then
                c.Offset(, 1).Value = "Avaialable"
            ElseIf InStr(ele.Text, "taken") Then
                c.Offset(, 1).Value = "Not Avaialable"
            Else
                c.Offset(, 1).Value = "Unknown"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next c

Stop
End Sub
```

I need to open each link in a new tab and check for the domain (available or taken) but I got errors as for the element (because of the page loads)
Any suggestions how to improve the code so as to work faster and to avoid errors?

Comment: Tell us more about the incorrect results times... can you supply failing cases with expected results.

Comment: Increase delay time? E.g. bot.Wait = 10000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the API which has a field for this. There is an exact match API as well as a cross sell.

Exact match

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckDomainAvailability()
    Dim json As Object, domains(), i As Long, url As String
    domains = Array("google.com", "bszadfdws.com")
    url = "https://find.godaddy.com/domainsapi/v1/search/exact?q=####&key=dpp_search&pc=&ptl=&itc=dpp_absol1"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For i = LBound(domains) To UBound(domains)
            .Open "GET", Replace$(url, "####", domains(i)), False
            .send
            Debug.Print JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)("ExactMatchDomain")("IsAvailable")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Cross sell to look at related domains:

```
https://find.godaddy.com/domainsapi/v1/crosssell/all?sld=domainNameGoesHere&key=dpp_search&pc=&ptl=&itc=dpp_absol1
```

You would then need to look at the value for key `CrossSellDomains` instead of `ExactMatchDomain`

---

**Requirements:**

1. Download and add to your project jsonconverter.bas from [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas)
2. VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime

---

**Selenium version:**

Used timed loop and check contents of header for `available`.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub CheckDomainAvailability()
    Dim d As WebDriver, domains(), i As Long, t As Date, ele As Object
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 10
    domains = Array("google.com", "bszadfdws.com")
    Set d = New ChromeDriver

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        For i = LBound(domains) To UBound(domains)
            .get "https://ae.godaddy.com/domainsearch/find?checkAvail=1&tmskey=&domainToCheck=" & domains(i)

            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .FindElementByCss(".exact-header-tag")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing
            If Not ele Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print domains(i) & " available = " & (InStr(LCase$(ele.text), "available") > 0)
                Set ele  = Nothing
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I encountered Dictionary Key not found :HasIcannfee at this line `json_ParseObject.Item(json_Key) = json_ParseValue(json_String, json_Index)`

Comment: Please provide the failing search domain. Also, that is not a key I am using.That is not the key for availability.

Comment: I wonder if it is a language thing. That might then be a problem for the parser. The above runs fine for me.

Comment: What happens if you debug.print .responsetext   - what do you get?

Comment: There's a responsetext and here's part of it `,"ExactMatchDomain":{"AuctionId":0,"AddToCartCallback":"https://find.godaddy.com/v1/addtocart?domain_guid=af0389ba-b35d-474b-ba1a-7f1eaa2831ac","DomainGUID":"af0389ba-b35d-474b-ba1a-7f1eaa2831ac",`

Comment: I found this part that may work but how can I use it `"IsAvailable":false,`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192653/discussion-between-yasserkhalil-and-qharr).